# Download a PDF file in a folder with the same name as that of PDF in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to have a functionality like on a button click I am able to download a PDF say 1.PDF but that PDF file should download into a folder named 1 and not just outside on desktop etc. How can we create a folder with the name of that PDF and then save that PDF in that folder. Need to use angular js. Any ideas? Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

New here so I have to post this as an answer rather than a comment. Websites aren't allowed to create folders on users' systems, and you can't get JavaScript to set the destination of a file download. I think there might be are some hacks available but these won't be well supported, so would be a very flaky solution.

Instead perhaps zip up the 1.PDF in a file called 1.zip on the server, then the user will download that and can choose to auto unzip it into a new folder called 1.